# Spring REST authentication - Chrome ignores cookie

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, axios

I have frontend in React and backend in Spring Boot and I'm trying to have REST authentication.
The problem is that I get header `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=221DC95570C24409E1F21B1ED954BDA9; Path=/; HttpOnly` but chrome never actually sets the cookie, so after login when I try to call an endpoint with axios and `withCredentials: true` set I'm getting 401 as if I'm trying unauthenticated to reach my backend endpoint. I read somewhere that cookie is never set because frontend is `localhost:3000`. Is there any way around it? Or better way to configure REST authentication through Spring? Without doing full authentication manually.

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
  @Autowired
  private RESTAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
  @Autowired
  private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
  @Autowired
  private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
    http.cors();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/*/public/**", "/api/security/**", "/api/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler());
    http.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/api/auth/login").successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
    http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
    http.logout().logoutUrl("/api/auth/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessHandler((new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK)));
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
  }

  @Bean
  public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "x-csrf-token", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }

}
```

**WebConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "OPTIONS").allowedHeaders("Content-Type",
            "X-Requested-With", "accept", "Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", "x-csrf-token")
        .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials").allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
  }

}
```

One more question, any idea why CORS is set everywhere to localhost but authenticated endpoints are returning wildcard? It might be because it's throwing currently 401 for them?

EDIT:

Login request
[image]

Authenticated user endpoint
[image]

Spring log says unauthenticated (understandable)

```
2019-01-12 21:04:09.281 DEBUG 13320 --- [nio-8091-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@64212f9d: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
```

Comment: Not sure what is the expectation you are getting, share some logs to help. Just to clarify ```Set-Cookie:```this is forward by the browser(chrome) so there is no issue with chrome/browser.

Comment: @dur Added requests screenshots @Barath I know it's browser standard, I was curious if there was some spring configuration that can change using `Set-Cookie` to something like header or something where I don't have a problem with Chrome. As you can see from screenshot I tried without port but didn't help

Comment: @dur yes, `Allow sites to save and read cookie data` is on

Comment: @dur I tried that but I can't, javascript can't access cookies data, browser doesn't allow it for that case, and when I tried to add endpoint to get sessionId then it doesn't work because login always returns new sessionId so my last one is not for an authenticated user, tried also getting after still getting new session. Also played with Spring generating session policies but didn't get it to work

Comment: @rbiggy Okay, I can't help you, but remember REST is stateless. You should not use a session. Use instead HTTP basic authentication.

Comment: Using cookies would be an incorrect choice for stateless REST API invocations. I would suggest using OAuth2. We've created a [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4BHKcZ2rxk) on the subject to give you an introduction. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4BHKcZ2rxk